# Issues with mysql2 with and ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

Trying to get the gem mysql2 installed on ubuntu and I have tried all of the suggestions but I cannot get it to run. Here is the error in my application.

```
./bla.rb:65:in `post_init': undefined method `query' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/timers.rb:51:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/em/timers.rb:51:in `fire'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
    from ./bla.rb:234:in `start_server'
    from ./bin/minibardaemon:15
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/application.rb:254:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/application.rb:254:in `start_proc'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/application.rb:263:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/application.rb:263:in `start_proc'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/application.rb:295:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/controller.rb:73:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons.rb:197:in `run_proc'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/daemons-1.1.8/lib/daemons.rb:196:in `run_proc'
```

I have installed all of the packages that are recommended and installed mysql2 via gem but still no luck.

```
libmysqlclient-dev
```

Is installed.

Im on Ubuntu.

```
# gem -v
1.3.7

# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]
```

Installing the gems

```
# gem install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.8.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.8.1...



# gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...


  def create_mysql2
    begin
      mysql2 = Mysql2::EM::Client.new(
        :username => DBUSER,
        :password => DBPASS,
        :host     => DBHOST,
        :port     => DBPORT,
        :socket   => DBSOCKET,
        :database => DBNAME
      )
      return mysql2
    rescue Mysql2::Error => exception
      $stderr.puts "Mysql Error: #{ exception.message }"
      EventMachine::stop_event_loop
    end
  end
```

...

```
begin
    mysql2 = create_mysql2
rescue Exception => ex
    p ex
end

    # query the db every x seconds.
    EventMachine::add_periodic_timer(QUERY_INTERVAL) do
      defer1 = mysql2.query "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT #{QUERY_LIMIT}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't realy look like mysql2 gem issue, could you please show 65'th line of you `bla.rb` file? And probably some number of lines that surround it.

it actually looks like your mysql2 client gets uninitialized for some reason.
I would advice to check if something like this works:

```
require 'mysql2'
mysql_client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root")
mysql_client.query('sql .. ')
```

if so, there's clearly an issue in your script

Comment: line 65: defer1 = mysql2.query "SELECT * FROM minibar_usage where status = false LIMIT #{QUERY_LIMIT}" -> Updated my question with more code.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction - this was the acutal problem: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/112 - Needed to start the connection every time.